# Facebook like button with button_count layout missing space

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, send, styling

Since last week, my Facebook like button with count display + send button ("button_count layout" as they name it in their plugin page) is looking weird, missing the blank space there used to be between the "like" count and the "send" buttons. First I thought it had something to do with Wordpress and the plugin being used to display it since I first noticed it in my WP based site, but after investigating I've come to the conclussion that Facebook has changed the styling without advice. It is looking this way in their own plugin page, tested with different browsers and operating systems.

This is how it looks now. Notice the lack of space between like count and the send button:

[image: Facebook button missing the space between like count and send]

This is how it used to look until one or two weeks ago:

[image]

Has anyone else noticed this change? I still have not tried to add the missing spacing by any means because I am not yet sure if the change will be permanent or if it is some sort of "bug" by Facebook. I haven't been able to find any reference using Google about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after 9 days with no answers and having Facebook changed during this period the style of its "like with count + send" button, getting back the little gap between them, this question has lost its sense. It seems like they weren't minding a lot their "old" button since they were going to change it.

It seems also like I have such good aim making the right questions in the right moment! xD